# Fill view when passing a param using Linq to EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, function, linq-to-entities

The below code is working .. The CustomView is filled without any error.

**CustomView**

```
public static ProductView CustomView(Product data)
{
    var view = new ProductView();
    view.ID = data.ID;
    view.Number = data.Number;

    var invetoryCount = GetInvetoryCountNumber(data.Number);
    if (invetoryCount < 1)
        view.SoldOut = true;

    return view;
}
```

**Function**

```
public static List<ProductView> GetAll()
{
    using (var ctx = new DBSolutionEntities())
    {
        var data = ctx.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
        return data.Select(CustomView).ToList();
    }
}
```

I would like to add an additional param to the function to skip the inventory search

**CustomView - added bool**

```
public static ProductView CustomView(Product data, bool skipInvCheck)
{
    var view = new ProductView();
    view.ID = data.ID;
    view.Number = data.Number;

    if(skipInvCheck)
    {
        var invetoryCount = GetInvetoryCountNumber(data.Number);
        if (invetoryCount < 1)
            view.SoldOut = true;
   }    

   return view;
}
```

When I add bool param to CustomView and call it

```
public static List<ProductView> GetWithoutInvSoldOut()
{
    using (var ctx = new DBSolutionEntities())
    {
        var data = ctx.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
        return data.Select(CustomView, false).ToList();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I call return the filled view return data.Select(CustomView, false).ToList() when passing a param?

*p.s. When getting ONE record (not .ToList ), the CustomView works by 
return CustomView(data, false);*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue here is that the `Select` method expects a function that takes a single parameter, but `CustomView` takes two. The easiest way to solve this is to [*curry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the `bool` parameter into the `CustomView` method by using a lambda expression.

```
public static List<ProductView> GetWithoutInvSoldOut()
{
    using (var ctx = new DBSolutionEntities())
    {
        var data = ctx.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
        return data.Select(x => CustomView(x, false)).ToList();
    }
}
```